# Counting the posts of a loop (WP_Query)?

Tags: wordpress

I tried this way to display NO of post:

```
 <?php 
 $news_2 = new WP_Query( array (
     'post_type'=> 'jobs',
     'posts_per_page'=> '10', 
     'meta_key' => 'status_for_jobs',
     'meta_value' => '1'
 ) );

 if ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { 
     while ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { 
        $news_2->the_post();

        $count = $news_2->post_count;
 ?>

        <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>

 <?php 
      } 
 } 
 wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

if the NO of post = 0 i need to display this :-

```
<?php 
 $news_2 = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'=> 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page'=> '10', 
    'meta_key' => 'status_for_jobs',
    'meta_value' => '1'
 ) );

 if ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { 
     while ( $news_2->have_posts() ) { 

         $news_2->the_post();

         $count = $news_2->post_count;

         if ($count  == '0') {

       ?>

             <li><h3><a href="javascript:void(0)">No Post</a></h3></li>

       <?php
       } else {
       ?> 
             <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a</h3></li>

<?php  }  ?>

    <?php } } ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But instead of the total of posts, I not getting any thing.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you wanted to use was $news_2->found_posts instead of $news_2->post_count.